# Internet on Ubuntu Virtualbox without ICS?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, windows-xp, virtualbox, ics

is it possible to get internet on my Ubuntu Virtualbox without activating ICS on my Windows XP host?

Best,

T

EDIT:

I think it is not possible on my machine due to network policies...

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can you need to change the virtual box network settings. Before starting up the machine go to settings for the ubuntu machine and then go to netowrk. For one of your enabled adaptors change "Attached to" to Bridged adaptor and then select the netwrok interface you would like to piggy back on. Just shout if you still having problems,.

Comment: Ok, I tried this. Unfortunately it is not working. Ubuntu is trying to connect but cannot get a network connection...Any other possibilities? Do I need to setup a gateway or DNS?

Comment: Are you using a router? If so, check if you using MAC filtering as it maybe blocking your connection attemps.

Comment: Yes I am using a router but without MAC filtering. I can ping the network device on my host, but still no internet connection. I tried using NAT, bridge and host-only. Do I maybe need a combination of them?

Comment: Hold on let me take a look at my setup. I'm using win7 and virtual box but I know its possible as I had setup my xp machine and ubuntu virtual box but that was sometime ago.

Comment: Is your router using dhcp?

Comment: Yes. (I need to write atleast 15 characters.)